# Why is it called parshas Chayei Sarah

Tags: names, death, avot-patriarch-fathers, parashat-chaye-sara, imahot-matriarch-mothers

2 Weeks ago was Parshas Chayei Sarah, and in the beginning for the first Alia (portion) it spoke about how Abraham buried Sarah.And then for the next 6 Alia's it speaks about Yitzchok and the whole story etc. So if so little of the Parsha speaks about Sarah so then why is the parsha dedicated to her, last Parshas (lech lecha) it mostly spoke about her, so maybe that parsha it could have said Chaya Sarah.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lubavitcher Rebbe [explains](http://www.chabad.org/parshah/article_cdo/aid/2524428/jewish/In-the-Garden-of-the-Torah-Chayei-Sarah.htm) that every event in the parsha represents the triumph of Sarah's view and approach.

First, the purchase of Ma'aras HaMachepeilah shows the actualization of G-d's promise in the world. She passed away unable to take the news that Yitzchak was almost sacrificed because her focus was on serving G-d within the world, not negating it.

Then Yitzchak marries Rivkah, who's spiritual values represented a continuation of Sarah (as we see from the three miracles resuming with her return).

When Avraham remarries, he of his own initiative sends away the other children and makes Yitzchak his heir, thus validating Sarah's insistence at sending away Yishmoel.

And even Yishmoel accepts this at the end of the Parsha, where he lets Yitzchak go first at Avraham's funeral, accepting Sarah's view that Yitzchak was the predominant one.

So the parsha speaks about the permanence of what Sarah accomplished in her life.

Answer (score 4):

[msh210 is correct](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48816/5323) but... al pi drush one can say the main part of the parsha revolved around Yitzchok's finding a wife. This happened in large part as his emotional replacement for his mother as the Torah attests at the end of chapter 24 'and Yitzchok was comforted after his mother'. 
Another point is kabbalisticaly speaking, as brought in Chida and others there was an interesting mix up of male and female souls and Yitzchok lost his feminine soul by the Akeida, and Rifka got Sara's so again, the death of Sarah was a key factor in the major part of the parsha.

Answer (score 3):

Like the colloquial name of every other *parasha*, *Chaye Sara*'s comes from its initial words.